# Unique local solution of an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Considering the initial value problem:

$$ \left\{\begin{matrix} \dot{x}=x^2yz
 \\ \dot{y}=xy^2z
 \\  \dot{z}=-2xyz^2
\end{matrix}\right.$$

with $x(0)=y(0)=z(0)=1$

How to show that there is an unique local solution and could we also find an explicit solution?

Answer (score 1):

The local existence of a unique solution follows from the fact that the right-hand side is locally Lipschitz.

Let $u:=\log(x)$, $v:=\log(y)$, and $w:=\log(z)$. Then, we have that

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{u}&=&\dot{x}/x=xyz=\exp(u)\exp(v)\exp(w)=\exp(u+v+w)\\
\dot{v}&=&\dot{y}/y=xyz=\exp(u)\exp(v)\exp(w)=\exp(u+v+w)\\
\dot{w}&=&\dot{z}/z=-2xyz=-2\exp(u)\exp(v)\exp(w)=-2\exp(u+v+w)
\end{array}
$$
together with $u(0)=v(0)=w(0)=0$.

Observe that $\dot{u}+\dot{v}+\dot{w}=0$, therefore we have that $u(t)+v(t)+v(t)=u(0)+v(0)+v(0)=0$ for all $t\ge0$. This implies that

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{u}&=&1\\
\dot{v}&=&1\\
\dot{w}&=&-2
\end{array}
$$
together with $u(0)=v(0)=w(0)=0$. The solution to the above system is $(u(t),v(t),w(t))=(t,t,-2t)$, which implies that $(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(e^t,e^t,e^{-2t})$.